# How can I edit my normalize function so that it also removes punctuations and end of line characters

Tags: python

How can I edit my normalize function so that it also removes punctuations and end of line characters?

Code sample below:

```
    filename="bible.Sentences.15.txt"

    def getData(filename):
      with open(filename,'r') as f:
        #converting to list where each element is an individual line of text file
        lines=[line.rstrip() for line in f]
        return lines

    filename="bibleSentences.txt"
    getData(filename)
    
    def normalize(filename):
        #converting all letters to lowercase
        lowercase_lines=[x.lower() for x in getData(filename)]
        print(lowercase_lines)
        return lowercase_lines  

    normalize(filename)
```

Comment: I tried using punctTable = str.maketrans(‘’,’’,string.punctuation) but it gave an error. Would really appreciate it if someone could help with this

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Please include a minimal example of the text in the file. Please read [mre]. `I tried using ... str.maketrans` - you should include that attempt in your mre and explain why it didn't work, why was the result different than you expected.

Comment: `removes ... end of line characters` - doesn't `line.rstrip()`, in `getData`, do that?

Comment: First few lines of the text are:in the beginning god created the heaven and the earth.
and the earth was without form and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep.
and the spirit of god moved upon the face of the waters.
and god said let there be light and there was light.
and god saw the light that it was good and god divided the light from the darkness.
and god called the light day and the darkness he called night.
and the evening and the morning were the first day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do that:

```
import re

...

def normalize(data):
    #converting all letters to lowercase
    lowercase_lines=[x.lower() for x in data]
    # strip out all non-word or tab or space characters
    stripped_lines = [re.sub(r"[^\w \t]+", "", x) for x in lowercase_lines]
    print(stripped_lines)
    return stripped_lines
```